# How to include two foreign keys in a table in jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, foreign-keys

I'm using JDBC in eclipse IDE , i want to put two foreign keys in my table 3 , one is referencing to the primary key in table 1 and one is referencing to the primary key in table 2. When i only put one foreign key constrains for any referencing table1 or table 2 , it works fine but when i include two it gives me sql exception as stated below:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'foreign key(`T2`) references
>   Table2(`T2`) )' at line 1

```
String createString =
// TABLE 1
"CREATE TABLE " + this.tableName + " ( " +
                "T1 varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY )";   
// TABLE 2
"CREATE TABLE " + this.tableName + " ( " +`enter code here`
                "T2 varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY )"; 
// TABLE 3
"CREATE TABLE " + this.tableName + " ( " +
                "T1 varchar(50) " +
                "T2 varchar(50) " +
                "foreign key(T1) references Table1 (T1)" +
                "foreign key(T2) references Table2(T2) )";
```

Comment: I would suggest providing a more complete example of your code. It appears you have left out reassignment of `this.tableName` and execution of the statement between each iteration. We can assume that is what you have done, but without more complete code you could be having a different problem than what can be deduced from your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is actually a MySQL question, unrelated to Java/JDBC. Secondly, and more importantly, you don't appear to be using the correct syntax, which would be...

```
CREATE TABLE TableName ( 
    T1 varchar(50),
    T2 varchar(50),
    foreign key(T1) references Table1(T1),
    foreign key(T2) references Table2(T2) 
);
```

Formatted for your code, it would look like this:

```
String createString = "CREATE TABLE " + this.tableName + " ( " +
    "   T1 varchar(50)," +
    "   T2 varchar(50)," +
    "   foreign key(T1) references Table1(T1)," +
    "   foreign key(T2) references Table2(T2));";
```

You were missing commas after each item in the items list for your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: yes, this syntax works , thank u so much , but there should also be a plus(+) before this.tableName :)

Comment: ofcourse i accept it ,i mean is there something that i have to click for your answer to be displayed as the correct one?